# replace last ip with **

Tags: php, regex

I want to be able to replace the numbers between the last two octets ***
Like 192.168.10.129

```
to : 192.168.**.***
```

I need regex to do that.

Comment: Is this an homework? Why do you "need" regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/(\d+\.\d+\.)\d+\.\d+/", "$1*.*", "192.168.10.129");
```

Comment: Technically doesn't answer the question (check the number of asterisks output).

Comment: Special for you: `for ($m=2, $i = strlen($ip)-1; $m > 0; $i--) if ($ip[$i] == '.') $m--; else $ip[$i] = '*';`
;-)

Answer (score 2):

$temp_array = explode(".", $old_ip);

$new_ip = $temp_array[0].'.'.$temp_array[1].'.'.str_repeat('*', count($temp_array[2])).'.'.str_repeat('*', count($temp_array[3]))

+1 for creativity ?